# My Azure Web Application reported a memory related autoheal. How does Proactive Auto Heal know when to restart my Web App?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

My Azure Web Application reported a memory related auto heal. However, memory consumption never reached 90% on My Web App. How does Proactive Auto Heal know when to restart my Web App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, as you mentioned that the memory consumption on you Web App has never reached   90%, makes me think that your App was not restarted because of Proactive Auto Heal.

Proactive Auto Heal looks for Web Apps that breaks either of these rules:

Percent Memory Rule: This rule monitors the Web App’s process’ private bytes to see if it exceeds 90% of the limit for over 30 seconds.

Percent Request Rule: This rule monitors requests that have taken longer than the time limit. It is broken when 80% (or more) of total number of requests have taken 200+ seconds.

If either of the rules are broken, then the Web App will undergo a overlapped restart of the process.
More about Proactive Auto Heal can be found here:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/08/17/proactive-auto-heal/
In this case, it could be that your app must be behaving as per the auto heal rule that someone with access to the site must have set for this slot at some point at your end.

There could be a rule either in Azure Portal or in your Web.config file defining memory limit for your Production slot. You should be able to verify the same by following below mentioned steps:

Where to check in Azure Portal:

•   Go to Diagnose and Solve page with in your WebApp .

•   On the right-hand side, you will see Support Tools category, under that please select mitigate:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Sthh.png

•   You will then see Configure Mitigation Rules, please check if Auto-Healing there is Enabled and if so what is that you see under Memory Limit?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbNDt.png

If you see the rule is configured, then you know that the application hit the Memory Autoheal limit and was recycled. Misconfigured Auto Heal rules can cause frequent app restarts, which may be undesirable.
Recommendation:
Check Auto Heal Settings: Make sure that your auto heal configurations are not causing undesired app restarts.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. 

Understanding that Proactive autoheal is different than the autoheal configured in our app makes 100% sense. 

We will mitigate this issue as you outlined.